# How do I "unzip" a gzipped stream while reading it

Tags: c++, stream, gzip

My program is using HTTP to read **gzipped** files over the network.
I need my program to be able to unzip the content and parse it even when not all the gzipped file arrived yet.
Can it be done ?
If so, can it be done in C++ ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably try out the [gzstream](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) library:

> Gzstream is a small C++ library,
>   basically just a wrapper, that
>   provides the functionality of the zlib
>   C-library in a C++ iostream. It is
>   freely available under the LGPL
>   license.

Comment: I need to decompress gzipped content in memory. I didn't see how this library can help me.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.zlib.net/

Zlib is able to read gzip. Have a look at the manual. http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Gzip

Comment: All I see is gzip related functions related to handling gzipped files from disk. I need to ungzip gzipped stream in memory

Comment: shoot!

Search the docs http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Introduction with "gzip" and many sections appear describing the behavior when dealing with gzip streams. From that and the introductory text in the docs I draw the conclusion that reading gzip streams is possible through the usual inflate / deflate interface.